# Can't start Outlook desktop client - "The set of folders cannot be opened"

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I've gone to load Outlook this morning, and I am presented with this. I can't load into safe mode, and I don't know which folder it can't open as it doesn't tell me.

[image]

Version is 16.0

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happens when there are two or more entries in the Data Files tab of Mail settings (via control panel), and the wrong Data File is loaded, or the data file isn't locally available (OneDrive inaccessible).

Change the default Data File to the one you have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to know that you have solved this issue. As a supplement, when this issue occurs, it may also be caused by a corrupted Outlook profile. It is recommended that you could try to create a new Outlook profile (Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add your account to check if there're any differences.